# Why is unordered_map "find + insert" faster than "insert + check for success"?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using an unordered_map as a sparse 3D-array (128 x 128 x 128) to insert values into a grid, provided the grid cell is still free.

Up until now I always checked with find() if the cell is free and if it is, then I've added an element using insert() or emplace().
Now I've found that I can use the return value of insert and emplace to check if the element has been added or if there was already an element with the same key inside the map. I thought this could improve performance since I could completely remove the usage of find.

As it turns out, rather than improving the performance by inserting without find, the performance actually decreased and I'm not sure why.

I've reduced my application to this example where points are randomly generated and then inserted into the grid.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::unordered_map;

int num_elements = 5'000'000;


void findThenInsert(){
    cout << endl << "find and emplace" << endl;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::mt19937 gen(123);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 128);

    unordered_map<int, int> grid;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++){
        float x = dis(gen);
        float y = dis(gen);
        float z = (cos(x*0.1) * sin(x*0.1) + 1.0) * 64.0;

        int index = int(x) + int(y) * 128 + int(z) * 128 * 128;
        auto it = grid.find(index);
        if(it == grid.end()){
            grid.emplace(index, count);
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "elements: " << count << endl;
    cout << "load factor: " << grid.load_factor() << endl;

    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    long long duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    float seconds = duration / 1000.0f;
    cout << seconds << "s" << endl;
}


void insertThenCheckForSuccess(){
    cout << endl << "emplace and check success" << endl;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::mt19937 gen(123);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 128);

    unordered_map<int, int> grid;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++){
        float x = dis(gen);
        float y = dis(gen);
        float z = (cos(x*0.1) * sin(x*0.1) + 1.0) * 64.0;

        int index = int(x) + int(y) * 128 + int(z) * 128 * 128;
        auto it = grid.emplace(index, count);
        if(it.second){
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "elements: " << count << endl;
    cout << "load factor: " << grid.load_factor() << endl;

    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    long long duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    float seconds = duration / 1000.0f;
    cout << seconds << "s" << endl;
}

int main(){

    findThenInsert();
    insertThenCheckForSuccess();

}
```

In both cases the size of the map is 82901 afterwards so I assume the result is exactly the same.

```
find and emplace:   0.937s
emplace then check: 1.268s
```

Comment: IIRC, `emplace` for `unordered_map` must allocate regardless of whether the key is present, so you are paying for some extra allocations in the second case.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant That [is C++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal): "Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a separator, they are ignored by the compiler."

Comment: @ChrisDrew oh, that is quite nice, didn't realize that.

Comment: @T.C. why does it need to allocate?

Comment: @n.m emplace takes `Args&&... args` you need to construct something with those args before it can compare it against the other keys and as I understand common implementations of emplace will construct in the desired destination (dynamically allocated in memory) and delete it if it is not required.

Comment: @ChrisDrew you compare keys, not values. If you had a set instead of a map that would be true.

Comment: @n.m. You emplace a `value_type`, which is the pair. You can't use the key for anything until you actually have it constructed, and once constructed you can't move it, so it has to be constructed at its final location.

Comment: @T.C. Value type is an std::pair. If you have two arguments, the first one will always be the key, or at least this common case can always be specialized for (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @T.C. Even if you have an unmovable key, and an argument that is not the key so that you need to construct the key, and you indeed need to construct the key at its final location, you can always avoid unneeded allocations. Say you have allocated a value type and the key is present in the map? fine, destruct the value type but don't free the memory, store a pointer to it n a special little place in the map so that next time you don't have to allocate it.

Comment: @T.C. Another thing an implementation could possibly do is construct a temporary key and then if needed, construct the final key-value pair. In this method you have one wasted key construction and in the other method you have one wasted value-type construction. It is not clear why one would prefer the latter.

Comment: You probably want to output the load factor and number of elements after you calculate the duration. You've done two flushes to cout and those might well contribute something noticeable to the timing.

Comment: @n.m. You can only construct the key once, since that construction can move from the arguments.

Comment: @T.C. C++17 should fix it all anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that the specification of `emplace` for associative containers in effect requires an allocation even in the failure case; the cost of this allocation and reallocation dominates the cost of a failed probe in the find-then-insert strategy.

This is because `emplace` is specified to emplace-construct `value_type` (i.e. `pair<Key const, T>`) from its forwarded arguments; only once it has constructed the pair can it hash the key to check whether it is already present. (It can't just take the first argument, because that could be `std::piecewise_construct`.) It also can't construct the `pair` in automatic storage and then move it into a node, because `emplace` is not specified to require a copyable or even movable `value_type`, so it has to perform a potentially expensive node allocation on every call. (Note that the ordered associative containers have the same problem, but there the O(log n) cost of a probe is more significant compared to the cost of allocation.)

Unless your inserts are expected to succeed in the majority of cases, you are better off using find-then-emplace over emplace-then-test. You could also use `insert`, as long as you make sure you're calling the `value_type` overload and not the template that forwards to `emplace`.

This is (probably) fixed in C++17, which (should) have [`try_emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace), with similar semantics to emplace but improved performance in the failure case. (The semantic difference is that the mapped type is not emplace-constructed in the failure case; this makes it possible to e.g. store `unique_ptr` as the mapped type.)

Comment: @ChrisDrew yes, but you have to be careful - the template overload of `insert` forwards to `emplace`. I think this is also fixed in C++17, though.

Comment: Please quote your sources. Map-type containers have separate keys and values. Only keys are compared/hashed. There is no need to construct the pair to hash/compare the key. map::find somehow manages to do so. `(It can't just take the first argument, because that could be std::piecewise_construct.)` This part is unclear. Please explain.

Comment: @n.m. `map::find` has a `key_type` argument; `emplace` just has a pack of undifferentiated arguments that are forwarded to the constructor of `value_type`. All sources for this are the C++ standard, clause **[unord.req]**, specifically the table *Unordered associative container requirements (in addition to container)*.

Comment: @n.m. **[pairs.pair]** /16 is the `pair` constructor in question.

Comment: Got the reference. An implementation can always check and specialize for the first arg type being `std::piecewise_construct_t`.

Comment: @n.m. unfortunately not - that would require either constructing the key twice, or constructing it and then moving it into the node; neither are countenanced by the specification of `emplace`. Same goes for the converting template constructors of `pair`, come to think of it.

Comment: "constructing the key twice" the standard says nothing about constructing a value_type when a key exists, yet it is somehow deduced that it must be constructed. Why value_type is OK and key is not?

Comment: @n.m. you're right; it would be OK to construct the key twice (but not to move it into the node). However, that would be fragile (`emplace` would have to perfectly simulate the constructors of `pair` to construct just the key) and would be a pessimization in the success case.

Comment: If the first argument has exactly the key type, one can hash/compare it directly instead, since copy constructor is going to be used, and we are allowed (I think) to optimize away the copy. In any case can specialize for common key types (strings, integrals, tuples thereof...), we are definitely allowed to optimize away copies of those.

Comment: @n.m. these are all things that the library implementor is allowed to do, but vendors will have different policies on whether the improved performance is worth the additional complexity. I imagine many vendors (especially open source projects) are likely to prefer that clients use code that is efficient even in the absence of such optimizations.

Comment: @n.m. It is possible that compilers are already performing such optimizations [my tests](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AtVYa7hHQ9y6Xl3k) with gcc 5.1.0 show that `emplace` is actually performing quite well.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I only have 4.9.3 here and alas it doesn't do any of this (checked in the source).

Comment: @n.m. looks like 5.2.0 always allocates the node also

Answer (score 7):

I think the issue is that you are using `emplace` instead of `insert`. The problem is that emplace functions in associative containers usually allocate memory for the node even if the key is already present. So that if you are regularly emplacing duplicates those memory allocations are wasted. If you used insert instead it would only do the memory allocation if the insert is successful.

Scott Meyers [says](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) to only prefer emplace functions over insert functions if "the container won't reject the value being added due to it being a duplicate"

I can't quite reproduce your results exactly but [my testing](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AtVYa7hHQ9y6Xl3k) shows that *insert* (not emplace) then test is even faster than find then emplace:

```
auto it = grid.insert({index, count});
```

This decision might also depend on how costly it is to create your value type. `find` does not need to construct the value type, it just needs the key. But `emplace` and `insert` need the key and the value type so in cases where it is costly to create the value it may be faster to use find and only create the value if you need to. In this case your value is just an `int` so I expect `insert` or `emplace` to always win over find-then-emplace.